# How To Customize Plot Area of CorePlot in Graph

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, graph, core-plot

I am plotting graph using core plot. I am trying to plot my graph on plot area, but it contains white background. But I want to plot graph with my own background. This is my code.

```
// setting frame of graph
CGRect frame = [self.hostingView bounds]; 
self.graph = [[[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];

// Add some padding to the graph, with more at the bottom for axis labels. 
self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop = 10.0f;  
self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 10.0f;  
self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 25.0f;  
self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 30.0f;

// set background color of plot area by fill property and CPTColor
self.graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea.fill=[(CPTFill *)[CPTFill alloc] initWithColor: [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0.8 green:0.8 blue:0.8 alpha:1.0]]; 

// add graph to hosting view by hostedGraph property of hostingView    
self.hostingView.hostedGraph = self.graph;
```

In above code I tried to change color but I want to draw horizontal dotted lines for each ticks on y axis.

Comment: Is your question about the plot area fill (what you have should work) or about the grid lines?

Comment: Hey !! Eric i want to draw horizontal dotted lines for each tickMarks on y-Aaxis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my code which i have used for above....

```
    // create an object of CPTMutableLineStyle and set property of it.

    CPTMutableLineStyle *dottedStyle=[CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    dottedStyle.dashPattern=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:1,[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:2],nil];
    dottedStyle.patternPhase=0.0f;

    // set the majorGridLinestyleProperty by this line as.

    axisSet.yAxis.majorGridLineStyle=dottedStyle;
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the `majorGridLineStyle` and/or `minorGridLineStyle` on the y-axis to draw horizontal lines at the major and minor tick locations, respectively.

Use the `dashPattern` and `patternPhase` properties of the line style to make a dotted line. See Apple's [Quartz 2D docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF105) for details on how those properties work.

Comment: Hey Eric this is not useful for me can you give me some code to explain it completely, because i am unable where to use this code.

Comment: Hey Eric i am trying to plot dotted lines with patternPhase and dashPattern but it is showing an error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found...

Comment: Hey Eric i found my answer like ..CPTMutableLineStyle *dottedStyle=[CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
 dottedStyle.dashPattern=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:1], 
        [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:2],nil];
 dottedStyle.patternPhase=0.0f;